# Is it possible to access static member variables within a generic method (C#)?

Tags: c#, list, oop, generics, static

Recently I tried to access a static list within a generic method but received an error when trying to do so. Is there a way to access a static variable within a generic method or is this not allowed? If it isn't allowed, would you mind explaining why and possible ways around this.

```cs
class Parent
{
    public static List<Parent> staticList = new List<Parent>();
    public Parent()
    {
        staticList.Add(this);
    }

    public static void RemoveItemFromList<T>() where T: Parent, new()
    {
        //This throws an error
        T.staticList.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public Child()
    {
        staticList.Add(this);
    }
}
```

When I hover over

```
T.staticList.RemoveAt(0)
```

(which is highlighted red) it states that: " 'T' is a type parameter, which is not valid in the given context ".

**Edit:**

Sorry about the confusion. Here is the amended code snippet:

How can I get this to work (without making the list non-static and whilst keeping the method generic):

```
class Parent
{
    public static List<Parent> staticList = new List<Parent>();

    public static void AGenericMethod<T>() where T: Parent
    {
        Console.WriteLine(T.staticList[0]);
        // This throws an error.
        // 'T' is a type parameter, which is not valid in the given context.
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public static new List<Parent> staticList = new List<Parent>();
}
```

Comment: why aren't you just doing `staticList.RemoveAt(0)`?  the static list is always going to be defined on the `Parent`.  If you need different lists in the children then it shouldn't be static.

Answer (score 2):

I will refrain from questioning your design. To answer your question, you don't need generics since all you are doing is removing the item at index `0`. All you need to do is to call the method:

```
public static void RemoveItemFromList() 
{
    staticList.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Note that with your current design, the child will be added **twice** to the static list as both constructors will be called. If this is not the desired behavior, remove the child's `staticList.Add(this);` call.

Even if you wanted to pass an object to be removed as a parameter, it would be sufficient to use the type `Parent` to pass all objects that derive from it without the need to use constraints:

```
public static void RemoveItemFromList(Parent item)
{
    staticList.Remove(item);
}

//These two would work just fine.
Parent.RemoveItemFromList(parent);
Parent.RemoveItemFromList(child);
```

**UPDATE:**

The OP changed the question so this addresses the second set of notes.

**THE ANSWER IS STILL THE SAME!**

This is because the fact that a method is generic does not mean different classes get generated under the hood.

Consider this:

```
public class Sample
{
    public static List<int> staticList = new List<int>();

    public static void AGenericMethod<T>() where T : Sample
    {
        //This works just fine. The static variable is shared by Sample and Sample2
        //Just don't try to qualify it with the generic type.
        staticList.Add(3);
    }
}

public class Sample2 : Sample
{

}
```

Usage:

```
var sample = new Sample();
var sample2 = new Sample2();

Sample.AGenericMethod<Sample>();
Sample2.AGenericMethod<Sample2>();
```

The (internal) result of this is a single static class instance with a variable containing two `3`'s that is shared by both classes. I believe this is what you want.

You can read [this interesting explanation](https://alexandrnikitin.github.io/blog/dotnet-generics-under-the-hood/) for further detail.

Comment: Sorry! I'm being really unclear as to what I am trying to achieve. I just provided the code as an example and just put some random code and constructors in to fill in the gaps. What I really want to know is if it is possible to access static variables from within generic methods.

Comment: @HenryDenny: I have updated my answer. Welcome to SO and next time try to lead with the **actual** question... :-)

Comment: @HenryDenny: Please take a moment to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that the child class overwrites (and must overwrite) the list from the parent class. In this scenario I have to use the form T.variableName but it does not allow me to.

Comment: Would you mind reading the edit I made to the original question?

Comment: @HenryDenny: Now it's time to question your design. What you are trying to do makes no sense. If you need to override it, why make it static? You need to rethink your design and apply OOP design principles properly.

Answer (score 2):

I think with the T you tried to swap between `Parent.staticList` and `Child.staticList`.

To my best knowledge, static is on priciple never affected by class inteheritance. There never **was** a static `Child.staticList`. It was always accessing Parent.StaticList.

There is only one way I know in wich a static can be affected by inheritance - if the static calls a instance function. The only example I can think of is [Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals). `public static bool Equals (object objA, object objB);` will call objA's `public virtual bool Equals (object obj);` after doing some reference related checks.

Note that you ar allowed to define static properties. And properties are mostly (but not completely) Syntax sugar for a get/set function pair.

Comment: Sorry! I'm being really unclear as to what I am trying to achieve. I just provided the code as an example and just put some random code and constructors in to fill in the gaps. What I really want to know is if it is possible to access static variables from within generic methods.

Comment: @HenryDenny Of course you can. Same way you do with all other Functions. All generics really do is allow you to put in a random type at compile time, helping you to maintain type safety.

Comment: Yeah that's what I would have thought but when I try accessing a static variable by using the form T.variableName it throws an error.

Comment: @HenryDenny Because there **IS** no T.variableName. There is only variableName.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Would you mind reading the edit I made to the original question once more? Thanks! :)

Comment: @HenryDenny: that does not tell me anything new. The only reason I can **imagine** for you to even **put** T there, is to swap between `Parent.staticList` and `Child.staticList`. Wich does not work, as there **never was** a `Child.staticList`. If that is not your intention, why **did** you put the T there? What purpose is it supposed to serve?

Comment: There is a Child.staticList: 
class Child
{
    public static new List<Parent> staticList = new List<Parent>();
}

Comment: It overwrites the Parent staticList

Comment: By the way, what you mentioned in your comment is exactly my intention.

Comment: @HenryDenny: That is a nice theory. What have you done to falsify it?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @HenryDenny: You have asumption about the behavior. But asumptions are not facts. You need to verify them. And the most reliable way is to try to disproove them.
And even **if** the theory is true, static should not be used to share data. Ever! Static Functions? Not an issue. Static constants or readonly's? Not an issue. A static running counter? *Maybe*. Static collections or data sources? Better do not.